# Converting form_remote_tag to form_for for Rails 3 UJS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I'm trying to convert this for Rails 3

```
<%= form_remote_tag :url => feedback_url, 
  :update    => 'flash_message', 
  :before    => "doSomething()", 
  :condition => "condition()", 
  :complete  => "doSomethingElse();" -%>
```

Here's what I have so far

```
<%= form_tag feedback_url, :remote => true, :id => 'form' do %>
  <%# Gather data %>
<% end -%>
<script>
    $(function() { 
      $("#form").bind("ajax:beforeSend", function() {
          doSomething();   
        }).bind("ajax:success", function() {
          doSmomethingElse();
        });
      });   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're well on your way. Is there something you're having trouble with in particular?

Comment: The `:condition` and `:update` options.

Comment: The form id `feedback_form` and jQuery selector `#form` don't match up in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this post for you. I am sure that you will solve https://web.archive.org/web/20201109001755/https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Comment: The linked post is no longer available 

Answer (score 1):

I like to do this a slightly different way.

```
<%= form_tag feedback_url, :remote => true, :id => 'feedback_form' do %>
  ...
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("form#feedback_form").submit(function(event){
    $('flash_notice').css('display', 'block');
    return condition() == true
  });
</script>
```

If the submit handler for the form returns false then it will not submit the form. (I'm pretty sure that is the case, but event.preventDefault() might work if that does not)
And this will also take care of the before conditions.

For the complete and update though I find it better to use a different template. For instance, lets say that you form submits to the 'new'  action of some controller. You can have a template new.js.erb with

```
  $('flash_notice').css('display', 'none')
  doSomething();
```

In this template you also have access to instance variables defined in the controller.

Comment: Does the submit event actually get triggered with a `:remote => true` AJAX submitted form?

Comment: It sure does. And I just checked, when you return false, it won't actually fire off the AJAX event.

Comment: Cool. There's probably an argument to be made for using the UJS `ajax:beforeSend` hook and returning false from that to stop the request from happening.